# Event in Workbook not working when reopening

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel macro that creates a new custom workbook with events. The macro also copies the .bas and .cls files onto the new workbook and changes the link to be the new workbook.

When the new workbook is created, everything, including events works fine. But when I close it and reopen it, the events do not work anymore. I realize the new workbook value is been lost. Since I have a button on the sheet I added the following to try to recreate it but no luck:

```
Dim Newbook As New eventWB
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Set Newbook.Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set thisWB = Newbook.Workbook

// extra code to gather information
```

Comment: do you place the event code inside the sheet modules or ThisWorkbook module of the newly created workbook?

Comment: Hello @ScottHoltzman I have the code inside the eventWB.cls module which is located inside the new workbook

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with classes, but how would for instance a `Worksheet_Change` event know to fire if I change a cell on `Sheet1` in the new workbook if the code is in the class module?

Comment: since its inside the class module, I am creating the workbook as new eventWB. So its not a regular workbook. Each time I make a change on the cell, the workbook has this function inside of it so it will look it up as long as the application.enableEvents = true

Comment: Just to understand, you've created a custom class that catches all workbook events (possibly even custom events you generate). In your current (active) workbook, you use `Workbooks.Add` to create a new workbook and then copy your code modules/classes over to it. On a sheet in the new workbook, you have the code listed above (which creates an object of your custom event class). If you close all workbooks and then open the macro-created workbook, events do not work. Is this correct?

Comment: Hello @PeterT yes you are correct one thing is the custom class is the actual new workbook. So when I create this new workbook I create it as new eventWB instead of a regular wrokbook

Answer (score 0):

I beleive I found the solution to my problem. I was able to make it work by adding an extra lin on my workbook class:

```
Public WithEvents m_events As Application
```

Every time I open the workbook I call I set it as:

```
Newbook.m_events = Application
```

And it does the trick the events work again. Hope this helps anybody with the same issue! Thank you again!